# Display content of most recent custom post type on a page

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I'm building a page that will display a list of recent posts of a custom post type at the bottom, with the content of the most recent post displayed as the body of the page.

I've got the list of recent posts working, but I can't seem to figure out the latter half.

How do I display the body of a custom post type in my template?

Comment: That only posts the body of the page, not the body of the most recent post.

Comment: If you haven't created a new loop for the custom post type, how are you getting the list of most recent posts?

Comment: We may need to see the code that you're using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to create a new loop that pulls in the most recent custom post type, then displays its title and content.

```
<?php
    $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
        'posts_per_page' => 1 // put number of posts that you'd like to display
    ) );
?>

<?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>

          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>

          <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endwhile;?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Yup, this works perfectly! My knowledge of PHP is limited, and I have a hard time wrapping my mind around some of the concepts. This helps me solve my immediate problem, and helps to visualize some of the concepts a bit better. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: should really include 

    "post_status"=>"publish" 

in the query array so that you only get published items.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon this, post_status defaults to publish and is not needed anymore.